# How to use ubuntu to force all clients to use a specific dns

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns

Context:

In order to fix my huawei phone I need to use a trick that requires you to change the dns server that your router uses. Unfortunately my ISP disabled the ability to do so for the router they gave me. I now need to find a way to get my phone to use the correct dns so I thought that if I could host a hotspot on my ubuntu laptop (which "repeats" the normal internet connection) maybe I can get all clients that are connected to the laptop to use the dns.

However, I couldnt get it to work. My laptop now is able to access the site required (only works with the dns set) but all devices connected still use the normal router dns. What am I doing wrong?

Im using create-ap to make the hotspot

Comment: Setting the DNS is part of the DHCP protocol. Is your hotspot also acting as the DHCP server?

Comment: If I read the question correctly, you can use masquerading in Linux to do this. Disable DHCP on the main router, run DHCP on the device that's doing nat/masquerading (the laptop)